# iPhone: Execute code after animation of UIDeviceOrientation change finishes

Tags: iphone, animation, ipad, rotation

Not sure if I can explain this correctly, but I am trying to execute a method device orientation animation finishes. Right now I have `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self         selector:@selector(didRotate:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];`, but that triggers instantly. Is there a way to have it call `didRotate` after the view rotation animation is completed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement [`-didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:) in your UIViewController subclass. Put the `-didRotate:` stuff there, or call it.

Comment: Thank you, that worked like a charm. So there really is no reason to ever use the NSNotificationCenter approach, is there?